# Script Qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I want to use a field, present in the primary load, but in another load.

For example:

```
[Table 1]:
Select 
  Field1, 
  Field2
From 
  Database1
;

[Table 2]:
LOAD:
  if Field1(from Table 1) > 0 then 1 as Filter
Select 
  * 
From 
  Database2
;
```

I'm looking for the best way to use the `Field1` (from `Table 1`) in the `Table 2` in Qlikview. But it tells me that `Field1` is not present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are few options but in general its depends on your data:

- bring `Field1` into `Table 2`. If there is something common between `Table 1` and `Table 2` then you can to join both tables (or subset of them) and then `Field1` will be available in the resulting table. (This depends on your data but for me this is usually the preferred way)
- create variable(s) that holds specific `Field1` value. For example:

  ```sql
  [Table 1]:
  Select 
    Field1, 
    Field2
  From 
    Database1
  ;

  set vField1 = peek('Field1');

  [Table 2]:
  LOAD:
    if ($(vField1) > 0, 1, 0) as Filter
  Select 
    * 
  From 
    Database2
  ;
  ```

  In the script above [peek()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2023/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm) function will return the last loaded value from `Field1` and set the value into `vField1` variable, which is then used into `Table 2` load. Bear in mind that `peek()` returns only one value!
- [Lookup()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2023/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/LookUp.htm) function can look for a specific value in `[Table 1].Field1` based or not on the current field value from `Table 2`.

  ```sql
  ProductList:
    Load * Inline [
  ProductID|Product|Category|Price
  1        |AA     |1       |1
  2        |BB     |1       |3
  3        |CC     |2       |8
  4        |DD     |3       |2
  ] (delimiter is '|');

  OrderData:
    Load 
      *, 
      Lookup('Category', 'Product', ProductID, 'ProductList') as CategoryID
  Inline [
  InvoiceID|CustomerID|ProductID|Units
  1        |Astrida   |1        |8
  1        |Astrida   |2        |6
  2        |Betacab   |3        |10
  3        |Divadip   |3        |5
  4        |Divadip   |4        |10
  ] (delimiter is '|');
  ```

  In the example above `Lookup('Category', 'Product', ProductID, 'ProductList')` will look into `ProductList` table and into `Category` field and will return `Product` value based on the currently loaded `ProductID` value. So if there is a common values between `ProductID` and `Category` the result field `CategoryID` will contains data from the first table.